# Upgrading Selenium to 4.11.0 getting error class file for org.openqa.selenium.federatedcredentialmanagement.HasFederatedCredentialManagement not found

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

After upgrading Selenium version 4.6.0 to 4.11.0 receiving the following error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.federatedcredentialmanagement.HasFederatedCredentialManagement
  class file for org.openqa.selenium.federatedcredentialmanagement.HasFederatedCredentialManagement not found
```

JDK Version used: JDK 13.0.1

Could anyone share what needs to be updated along with the Selenium to fix the above issue?

Answer (score 2):

As Łukasz Bieliński said, have to update version for all selenium relevant dependencies to 4.11.0.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-grid</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```